# Calling Chatter API with in salesforce"INVALID_SESSION_ID"

Tags: apex, rest-api, rest

I am trying to call a chatter API with in salesforce and i am getting the below error message.
**Error Message:**

```
DEBUG|[{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]
```

**Code:**

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
req.setEndpoint('https://xxxxxxx.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v36.0/chatter/feeds/record/005a0000009pkIg/feed-elements');
req.setMethod('GET');
Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res= http.send(req);
String response=res.getBody();
system.debug(response);
ParseChatter pschatter=(ParseChatter)JSON.deserialize(response,ParseChatter.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this
`req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+UserInfo.getSessionId());`